# Get unique values from PostgreSQL array

Tags: postgresql

This seems like it would be straightforward to do but I just can not figure it out.  I have a query that returns an `ARRAY` of strings in one of the columns.  I want that array to only contain unique strings.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    f."_id",
    ARRAY[public.getdomain(f."linkUrl"), public.getdomain(f."sourceUrl")] AS file_domains,
    public.getuniqdomains(s."originUrls", s."testUrls") AS source_domains
FROM
    files f
LEFT JOIN
    sources s
ON
    s."_id" = f."sourceId"
```

Here's an example of a row from my return table

| _id | file_domains | source_domains |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2574873 | {cityofmontclair.org,cityofmontclair.org} | {cityofmontclair.org} |

I need `file_domains` to only contain unique values, IE a 'set' instead of a 'list'.  Like this:

| _id | file_domains | source_domains |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2574873 | {cityofmontclair.org} | {cityofmontclair.org} |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN public.getdomain(f."linkUrl") = public.getdomain(f."sourceUrl")
     THEN ARRAY[public.getdomain(f."linkUrl")]
     ELSE ARRAY[public.getdomain(f."linkUrl"), public.getdomain(f."sourceUrl")]
END
```